# Are there any known continuous (non-lattice) quantum error correction codes?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, black-hole-firewall

I come from a hep-th background, but I have noticed that quantum information is becoming increasingly common in discussions of AdS/CFT and black hole information, and so I've begun thinking about it lately. I'm heard much about the toric code and other quantum error correction codes, and I'm wondering if a continuous, non-lattice version of these codes exists. It seems certain that such a thing should exist in principle, but are there are known models, for example one based on a relativistic field theory?

Comment: I've not heard of codes like the ones you search for, but maybe this framework http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.7062 of Gottesman and Zhang might be interesting for you? Maybe this could be useful to construct codes of your type?

Comment: Charges in a topological field theory like Chern-Simons theory could be used to process quantum information in a self-error-correcting way. The basic idea is that you perform unitary rotations in the ground state manifold by braiding anyons. Keeping the anyons far away from each other prevents errors. [Witten's classic paper](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/857/art%253A10.1007%252FBF01217730.pdf?auth66=1423749353_21bc4abf18e444eb264719912daf532b&ext=.pdf) can be viewed as a prescription for a quantum algorithm to compute Jones polynomials with topological error correction built in.

Comment: The Witten paper is called ["Quantum Field Theory and the Jones Polynomial"](http://www.signallake.com/innovation/Witten89.pdf) (the other link seems to have died.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I know of that paper but I never heard it interpreted as a QEC, it sounds like I should revisit it. I think that for the application I had in the back of my mind, I was hoping to  find one where the information is more locally stored. And thanks Martin, I'll take a look at that one you cite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one thing, toric codes (and other error-correcting codes) are really about ways to store quantum information(logical qubits) in several physical qubits, so there is not much point in asking for a continuous limit. On the other hand, if you view it as a topological quantum phase of matter, then surely there are continuous versions. For example, the topological order of the toric code can be described by a Abelian Higgs theory(i.e. $U(1)$ gauge field coupled to charge-$2e$ matter). There are of course, generally Chern-Simons theory, as pointed out in @Mark Mitchison's comment. The idea of topological quantum computation(TQC) is to store quantum information in the degenerate non-local Hilbert space of multiple non-Abelian anyons, and use braiding to perform gate operations. But notice the difference between TQC from the toric code, since as a topological phase toric code only supports Abelian anyons. The logical qubit is related to the degenerate ground states when the toric code is placed on a torus, if I understand correctly.

Witten's paper is of course a classic on Chern-Simons theory. For the application to TQC this review(http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.1889) is a good place to start.

Comment: +1 for the Nayak et al. review, that's a great place to learn about these topics.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and references. When you say: "For one thing, toric codes (and other error-correcting codes) are really about ways to store quantum information(logical qubits) in several physical qubits, so there is not much point in asking for a continuous limit.", why do we need to have such a restrictive definition of error-correcting codes? Qubits are simple and do the job well enough, but the Hilbert spaces associated with QFT's should be able to support error-correction also, at least in principle. Could QEC be abstracted to a statement on the Hilbert space of a quantum theory?