# Can we write the effective field theory for the toric code model?

Tags: condensed-matter, field-theory, topological-field-theory, topological-order

If not, then why not? If yes, then what is the effective field theory?

Comment: You can construct the effective field theory for a 2+1D topological order by starting from the data of its fusion category: the anyons realized by the theory and their relations, and then finding the topological field theory that realizes this anyonic statistics. For the $Z_N$ toric code, that would be a doubled Chern-Simons theory if I remember well.

Comment: Everything is answered here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/164675/are-there-any-known-continuous-non-lattice-quantum-error-correction-codes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Effective field theory only describes system near critical point. Toric code model is far from critical point. Thus "No".

Toric code model realizes a $Z_2$-topological order. When a state with a $Z_2$-topological order is close to a continuous phase transition, then the state will have an effective field theory description. But which effective field theory will depend on which continuous phase transition the state is close to.